# Add Deployable Dependencies - missing MVC checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, dependencies

I am trying to use the new **Add Deployable Dependencies** feature of VS 2010 SP1 to help with deploying an MVC3 site to a shared hosting environment. However, when I select the option after right-clicking on the project, the resulting dialog box does not show the `ASP.NET MVC` checkbox. It only shows `Asp.Net Web Pages with Razor Syntax` and `SQL Server Compact`.

[image]

Another thing I noticed is the capitalization of `Asp.Net` does not match screenshots I've [seen online](http://paulstack.co.uk/blog/post/Using-Add-Deployable-Dependencies-in-VS2010-SP1.aspx). In the "About Microsoft Visual Studio" dialog box, my version is shown as `10.0.31118.1 SP1Rel`.

I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Solution**

I re-installed VS 2010 SP1 (via the Web Platform Installer) and I now have the `ASP.NET MVC` checkbox and the capitalization seems correct. In the "About Microsoft Visual Studio" dialog box, my version now shows as `10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel`... I must've still had the beta. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the project actually created as an Mvc project? If not you will have to add the Mvc project type GUID to the csproj file. Also make sure you actually have Mvc installed on your machine.

Comment: It was originally created as an MVC project and MVC is properly installed. However, I will check the GUID. Thanks!

Comment: Also make sure you have MVC 3 Tools Update installed. Not sure if it's required for the dependency deployment dialog, but it can't hurt.

Comment: If this goes to custard, you could use the 'old school' way and just add in references to the 6 dll's (from memory) that MVC3 needs :-)  I deploy to Azure and its only just got tooling support.  http://blog.smarx.com/posts/asp-net-mvc-in-windows-azure

Comment: Yeah, I did it the old school way just to get the deploy working for now. Good point on the tools.